# Multidemensional Array PHP with the same name

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Got a small question. Why this piece of code does only returns one package?

```
# Packages data
'packages' => [
    'package' => [
        'height' => '100',
        'width' => '200',
    ],
    'package' => [
        'height' => '1300',
        'width' => '2040',
    ],
    'package' => [
        'height' => '1200',
        'width' => '2020',
    ],
]
```

When I change the names to: packages_1, packages_2, packages_3 they output correctly but when I give them the same name it does only output one package. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: array indices must have different names, otherwise they are overridden, and you will get only the last.
From php doc - If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.
[array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Is it a dirty fix to give each of them a number or are there other options?

Comment: I guess you don't need the package names (if they're all the same anyway), in that case: Just drop it? (ie. remove `'package' => ` from those lines)

Comment: Use the numeric array indices. remove "package". 
'packages' => [
                '0' => [
                    'height' => '100',
                    'width' => '200',
                ], etc. When added to the array index values are increased by 1

Comment: @UserName Yeah that would be a better solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the associative array in PHP is a [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) so each key must be unique within the same array. You can fix this using one the these method:

1. Give each of the `package` keys a unique name (like you've already mentioned in your question).

For example:

```
'packages' => [
    'package_1' => [
        'height' => '100',
        'width' => '200',
    ],
    'package_2' => [
        'height' => '1300',
        'width' => '2040',
    ],
    'package_3' => [
        'height' => '1200',
        'width' => '2020',
    ],
]
```

2. Omit the key entirely and you'll have to access them using indexes.

For example:

```
'packages' => [
    [
        'height' => '100',
        'width' => '200',
    ],
    [
        'height' => '1300',
        'width' => '2040',
    ],
    [
        'height' => '1200',
        'width' => '2020',
    ],
]
```

And to access the values:

```
$myvariable['packages'][0]['height']
```